# Removing specific pattern from bash array digit_digit_digit etc

Tags: arrays, bash, pattern-matching

I have the following array

```
names=( 12_1_3_4_NAME1 1_2_4_NAME2 2_1_name3 1_nAmE4)
```

I want to remove the prefix and have

```
names=( NAME1 NAME2 name3 nAmE4 )
```

I tried some variantions of:

```
names=( "${names[@]/^\d+(?:\_\d+)/}" )
names=( "${names[@]//s*^\d+(?:\_\d+)+\s*/}" )
```

Based on a previous answer:

```
Use ^ to match the beginning of the string.
Use \d+ to match any number of digits.
Use \. to match a literal . character
Put \.\d+ in a group with () so you can quantify it to match any number of them.
Use re.sub() to replace it with an empty string to remove the match.
Use a raw string so you can put literal backslashes in the regexp without having to escape them.
patt = re.compile(r's*^\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s*')
string = patt.replace('', string
```

)

Without success! Im not sure how should I do it inside of an array

Comment: If there's no `_` in the parts you want to keep, you can simply remove everything from the beginning until the last `_` using `"${names[@]##*_}"`.

Comment: feeling dumb because I JUST used this to remove everything after the first underscore, for another usecase. I will leave the question open if there is the case that there is an underscore in the parts that I want to keep

Comment: `${//<this>` is not a REGEX, it is a glob. You posted regex rules. There is no `\d+` `^` etc in glob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
shopt -s extglob
names=("${names[@]//+([[:digit:]])_/}")
```

Answer (score 2):

The attempts in the question don't work because Bash string substitutions use glob patterns, not regular expressions.  For information about glob patterns see the [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Try

```
shopt -s extglob
names=( "${names[@]/#+(+([[:digit:]])_)/}" )
```

- `shopt -s extglob` enables extended globbing to support patterns like `+(...)`.  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).  There's no need to disable extended globbing after using it.  See [Is it dangerous to always have extglob on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276911/264812).
- The `#` in the pattern forces a match to be successful only at the start of the string.  See [Substituting part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Substituting_part_of_a_string).
- `+(+([[:digit:]])_)` matches one or more consecutive occurrences of one or more consecutive decimal digits followed by an underscore.

Comment: Great explanation!